# Trace performance in a farm

Tags: 2010, performance, troubleshooting, monitoring

I have 10 web applications in our SharePoint 2010 farm, these web applications loading very slowly and sometimes the application pool restarts.

How do I start tracing where the performance bottle neck is in our farm?
What are the recommended ways to find the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a Start point you can do following things:

- Check the Hardware on the SharePoint WFE( Memory Usage and CPU), check if/which process is eating up
- Drive space on the SharePoint Server
- SQL Server Hardware checks (Connections, Memory, CPU etc)
- Hardware should meet the min requirement
- if you have multiple servers then check each individual server.
- Check the ULS, IIS logs and Event Logs. Analyze them and get the clue
- See if search crawling cause the slowness
- Maybe backup either SharePoint or SQL Server cause this slowness
- Use the Developer Dashboard and check which component is taking too much for loading.
- Setup the performance counter and try to find the bottleneck.
- if you have customization then check if those have some kind of leaks.

Are you using separate App Pool for each web application then you already max the Microsoft recommendation? I think if that is the case then collapse the app pool on multiple web application bring down the numbers.

[SharePoint 2010: Tips for Dealing with Performance Issues](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7926.sharepoint-2010-tips-for-dealing-with-performance-issues.aspx)

Comment: thanks detailed explanation waqas, can you help me how to Setup the performance counter and try to find the bottleneck.?if you have good resource can you share here

Comment: if you check the mentioned link, it has information about it...but here is direct link https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/PowerShell-script-for-59cf3f70